# VB.NET Open image file from string

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a desktop environment for some of my older computers which struggle running windows' built in desktop. (I'm not using linux [no problems with linux, just generally prefer windows])

The current code doesn't work and I have no idea how to fix it!

```
 Dim als As Image
            als = Image.FromFile((My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FileIO.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\radon\config\wpp.radon")))
            Me.BackgroundImage = getpaper.Image
```

The file "wpp.radon" contains the following string:`C:\Users\pc\Pictures\AuBBTRo.png`

However it still does not work, what I intend it to do is read that string, and then use that to set the image (from that place). The user will have already selected the file using an opendialog which writes the path. However I cannot open that file again. I do not want the openfiledialog to show, because this is when everything is setup, it just needs to set the image as the wallpaper. I do not want to copy any files, I just need a "string to image" sort of converter, however nothing found on google. **I am using VB.Net 2010** and have no plans of upgrading to a newer one.

Comment: solved it by using an open file dialog, I added one and just manually set its file name and then loaded a picture box from that file name and set it as the background

Comment: `"wpp.radon"` is a string literal in the code.  it cannot contain or mean anything other than `"wpp.radon"`