# How to load background image from setting?

Tags: vb.net

Before I get into the actual problem, I've done some research and nothing helps. Also, this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008278/how-to-save-a-forms-background-image-using-my-settings-save-visual-basic) because s/he was using ComboBox, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576914/vb-net-open-image-file-from-string) is using an Open file dialog which does not help me.

Here is my problem. I am doing a Virtual System Overlay (some call it vb.net os) and for the "desktop" I need an background image loaded from an application setting. The problem is that I am getting this error:

> An unhandled expection of type 'System.IO.FileNotFounfExpection' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: My.Resources._2

And my code is:

```
Image.FromFile(My.Settings.bgdesk.ToString)
```

The setting looks like:

```
Name: bgdesk | Type: string | Scope: user | Value: My.Resources._2
```

Also, have a look at my resources:

[image: Example of resources]

How do I load the background image from the resource?

Comment: Try using `My.Resources` after saving whatever image you want on your resources folder

Comment: @TGamer What do you mean? To load image directly image from code like `Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._2` ? Nope, I want the user to be able to choose one from a list with buttons, which will save the choice and load it next time. I have 9 images, not 1.

Comment: I mean what you said just now. Use a `Select Case` to decide which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I properly understood your question, you want to dynamically load and save a background image setting, based on a user choice; the bitmaps to be used are already included in a resource file:

1) Create a Resource file named Resource1.resx
2) Insert bitmaps you want to use (e.g. named "_1", "_2"), in this file
3) In bgdesk, let the code save only the resource name (i.e. "_1", "_2")
4) Add a ComboBox cbImgList
5) Add a Button, which sets the new BackGround image when hit
6) Use the following code (adapt it to your needs)

```
Private Function GetBackGroundImgFromRes(ByRef sError As String) As Boolean

    Try

        Dim sImgName As String = My.Settings.bgdesk
        If sImgName.Trim <> "" Then
            Dim RM As Resources.ResourceManager = My.Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager
            Dim objBitmap As Object = RM.GetObject(sImgName)
            Me.BackgroundImage = DirectCast(objBitmap, Bitmap)
        End If

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        sError = ex.ToString
        Return False

    End Try

End Function

Private Function SetBackGroundImg(ByRef sError As String) As Boolean

    Try

        Dim sImgName As String = ""
        Select Case cbImgList.SelectedIndex
            Case -1
                Return True
            Case 0
                sImgName = "_1"
            Case 1
                sImgName = "_2"
        End Select

        Dim RM As Resources.ResourceManager = My.Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager
        Dim objBitmap As Object = RM.GetObject(sImgName)
        Me.BackgroundImage = DirectCast(objBitmap, Bitmap)

        My.Settings.bgdesk = sImgName

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        sError = ex.ToString
        Return False

    End Try

End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim sError As String = ""
    SetBackGroundImg(sError)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cbImgList.Items.Add("_1")
    cbImgList.Items.Add("_2")

    Dim sError As String = ""
    GetBackGroundImgFromRes(sError)

End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, you didn't understand my question. I DON'T want a combo box. I want like 9 buttons next to each other with sets new value in the setting. For example: Button 1 will set the setting's value to My.Resources._2 and buton 2 to My.Resources._3 .. I can do that but I can't ACTUALLY show the image as an background image.

Comment: @DimitarTheN00b Look more closely at the `SetBackGroundImg` method - it contains what you need, Raffaello was kind enough to provide enough code and instructions for *a* complete working answer.

Comment: Ok I will try it now again.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Haha it works now.. Sorry for being mean.. Just one more question: I am using different forms for my desktop and settings, how can I load the background to be in Form1.vb but not in Settings.vb ? Thanks.

Comment: NVM figured it out. Marked as best answer.